# Android Image Viewer for Webp and Animated GIFs

Tags: android, image-viewer, animation, archiving, file-format

Is there an Android application that can view webp and animated GIFs? It would be a plus if it could open .cbz files, or other archive formats, as I like to compress images on my phone. There are plenty of Comic Book viewers, and some of them support webp. But I haven't found any for Android that support animated GIFs.

Answer (score 1):

[Quickpic](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alensw.PicFolder) is very good at gifs and can also open webp.

For .cbz I recommend [Challenger Viewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kill.geek.bdviewer)